# Perl beginner: How can I find/replace ascii characters in a file?

Tags: perl, replace, find, ascii

I'm completely new to Perl and I thought that would be the best language to solve my simple task. I need to convert a binary file into something readable and need to find and replace strings like `\x00\x39` into `\x09` (tab) or something like that.

From bash, I started with the following and it works great:

```
perl -pi -e 's/abc/123/g' test.txt
```

However, when I start to enter ascii codes, I'm lost:

```
perl -pi -e 's/0x49/*/g' test.txt
perl -pi -e 's/{char(49)}/*/g' test.txt
```

How would this command would look like as a line in a perl script? I have about a couple hundred of these find/replacement operations and a 500MB text file. Are there any caveats that I would need to know?

Thanks so much for any help!

Gary

Answer (score 7):

Use the `\x##` notation:

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/\x00/*/g' test.txt
```

To replace each "special" character with its code in brackets, use the `/e` option:

```
perl -pi~ -e 's/([\x0-\x09\x11-\x1f])/"[" . ord($1) . "]"/eg' test.txt
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed; I was missing the backslash :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, thank you very much. I learned that it wasn't as easy as I assumed. Wow, Perl is truly very complex ;-)

Here is, what I came up with. I hope this will help someone.

BTW:  If you have any chance to know if this will also work on *Windows Perl*, please let me know.

Thanks again,

Gary

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = '/Users/gc/Desktop/a.bin'; 
my $outfile = '/Users/gc/Desktop/b.txt';    # in and out can be the same file; file will be overwritten when it already exists

my $data = read_file($infile);

# 1st batch
$data =~ s/0\x01J[\x00-\x19]/\x09AnythingYouWant\x09/g;
$data =~ s/0\x00[\x00-\x19]/\x09AnythingYouWant\x09/g;

# 2nd batch
$data =~ s/\r/\x06/g;                                   # CR into \x06
$data =~ s/\n/\x06/g;                                   # LF into \x06
$data =~ s/\r\n/\x06/g;                                 # CR LF into \x06

# …

write_file($outfile, $data);
exit;

sub read_file {
    my ($infile) = @_;

    open my $in, '<', $infile or die "Could not open '$infile' for reading $!";
    local $/ = undef;
    my $all = <$in>;
    close $in;

    return $all;
}

sub write_file {
    my ($outfile, $content) = @_;

    open my $out, '>', $outfile or die "Could not open '$outfile' for writing $!";;
    print $out $content;
    close $out;

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a bit weird to do string replaces on a binary file, here's how to do it with your txt file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my @file;
tie @file, 'Tie::File', 'test.txt' or die $!;

foreach (@file) {
  # your regexes go here
  s/abc/123/g;
  s/\0x49/*/g;
}

untie @file;
```

The [Tie::File module](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) (from the Perl core) allows you to access the lines of the file through an array. Changes will be saved to the file immediately. In the `foreach` loop, the file is processed line by line. The lines go into `$_`, which we cannot see. The regex operations are by default also applied to `$_`, so there's no need to write it down.

---

However, I believe you are going about this the wrong way. In most cases, you will not be able to just read the file line by line. Refer to [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-randomly-update-a-binary-file?) as a starting point. Dealing with binary is somewhat more tricky than just text processing I'm afraid.