# Remove a sequence of chars at the end of file including LF (linefeed)

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file that contains some PCL sequences. I have this sequence at the end of the file (hex):

```
461b 2670 3158 0a    F.&p1X.
```

I want to remove the sequence: <Esc>&p1X including the character that follows. In 99% of cases, LF follows the sequence.

I tried this command:

```
sed -b 's/\o33&p[0-9]X$//Mg' ~/test.txt >test2.txt
```

However, it appends LF at the end of test2.txt. Also, if, instead of `$` I specify `.` it doesn't match the line anymore.

If you want to play with this, generate the input file using this command:

```
echo -e "SomeString\033&p1X" > ~/test.txt
```

The redirect appends an LF char at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood well you know for sure that your file contains that sequence of characters at the end. If this is the case I would simply truncate the last six bytes. It will work regardless the very last character being new-line or whatever you want...

Example:

```
$ echo -e "SomeString\033&p1X" > test.txt
$ od -c test.txt
0000000   S   o   m   e   S   t   r   i   n   g 033   &   p   1   X  \n
0000020
$ truncate -s -6 test.txt 
$ od -c test.txt 
0000000   S   o   m   e   S   t   r   i   n   g
0000012
```

This is also very efficient as it will use the system call truncate().

Comment: Some files might not contain this sequence. That's why truncating would not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286743/perl-beginner-how-can-i-find-replace-ascii-characters-in-a-file):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\x1b&p[0-9]X\n//g' ~/test.txt
```

(I am a perl beginner as well - any comments would be appreciated).

Comment: What are the [other] non-newline chars that follow the `X`?  And what's the intent?  It looks like the file is mostly hex and you want to strip the non-hex line trailer?  Do you always want to strip the [optional] newline? If you're interested in perl, I've been writing it for 20+ years and I'd be happy to post an answer with a solution and some additional tips.  If you can post a data file that shows all the variants (e.g. 5-10 lines) that would also help

Comment: @CraigEstey what do you mean with "It looks like the file is mostly hex..."? Files are neither hex nor non-hex. Files just contain bytes you can represent in hex format or not.

Comment: @mauro Well, a "hex dump file" [or just "hex file"] means that the file contains the output of a hex dumper program (e.g. `od`, `xxd`, etc.).  I missed the "(hex)" and so the sample looked like a hex line (sans the alpha) and the trailer was some extra stuff that needed to be stripped to be able to read in the hex values on the left.  If I were posting the problem, I would have shown some of the valid left side data as that can sometimes influence what a regex can be [vs a hex dump with alpha for _just_ the bad part]